# COM - CoCreateInstanceEx always creates a new Object

Tags: c++, com

I am using the COM `CoCreateInstanceEx` API to create an instance of a specific class on a local computer.

I am using the same function again to get the instance which was created earlier but it creates a new instance.

Is it the right way to get the object of the class from running instance or should I use any other method ?

C++ Code snippet:

```
HRESULT nResult = CLSIDFromProgID(OLESTR("ABC"), &clsid);
MULTI_QI mqi[1];
mqi[0].pIID = &IID_IUnknown;
mqi[0].pItf = NULL;
mqi[0].hr = 0;

nResult = CoCreateInstanceEx(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, NULL, 1, mqi); 

IUnknown *pUnk = mqi[0].pItf;
```

Comment: To get an existing object from a running instance you'd use the running objects table (ROT). As I recall that's done via moniker. But it's very long ago, check it out. And instead of jumping through hoops to make that work you might just google it for some existing solution.

Comment: Googled it and ended up at `GetActiveObject`. There's also the lower level `CoGetObject`, which in turn uses, and so on. Unfortunately all these functions suffer from over-engineering, needless complexity.

Comment: You are "using the same function again to get..." while MSDN clearly states that this function "creates an uninitialized instance". What you actually get is clearly behavior by design.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf : Checked with the GetActiveObject method but no success, probably I am missing some step ....

Comment: @M.M - Yeah right ..

Answer (score 2):

> Is it the right way to get the object of the class from running instance or should I use any other method ?

No it is not. `CoCreateInstanceEx` delves into the depths of the COM factory mechanics to get the factory for the object required and creates a new one.

To get a "copy" of the same instance you last used, there are some options to choose from;

- Call `AddRef()` on the first created object to increment the COM objects reference count for the copy of the object pointer you are about to make. You then use that pointer until it is no longer required, then call `Release()`. The `Release()` decrements the reference count and, if it is the last reference, the COM object can destroy itself. This does not perform a deep copy of the object and its contents.
- If you have access to the code, you make the COM object a singleton or otherwise modify the lifetime as you require it. If the COM object code uses the ATL, there a several macros here that can assist, in particular [`DECLARE_CLASSFACTORY_SINGLETON`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b7b5axx6.aspx).
- Create a `Clone()` method on the COM object that performs the deep copy, the exact mechanism here would depend on the object itself, but typically it is nothing more than the usual coping the appropriate data fields.

Frankly though, unless this is an exercise in learning how COM works, **don't use naked pointers and try to manage the objects lifetime manually**. Use the ATL classes, in particular [`ATL::CComPtr<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezzw7k98.aspx) and it takes care of these issues as you would expect it to.

---

You don't specify in too much detail how and where the object is created. There are more advanced object registration and retrieval techniques that allow a greater level of control over the objects creation, lifetime and use. You could explore these if they are suitable;

1. The active object mechanisms of [`GetActiveObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221467(v=vs.85).aspx) et al.
2. If the object being used registers itself with the ROT (the running object table), you could also [explore the using the ROT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695276(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks @Niall for the suggestions, I have already tried with 'GetActiveObject' and using the ROT table. For the ROT table I need to create 'IMoniker' object for which I require object's name for the object being identified. I will need to find the unique name for the same.

Comment: @VirajAbhange. Sounds just about right. The ActiveObject and ROT requires the collaboration of the COM object that is created. Your intent is not completely clear from the code sample you provide, but I think a simple `AddRef` will do, or better to use the ATL.